# What kind of shell would protect against a a stabbing/piercing weapon on a predator's tail?

Tags: evolution, fauna, natural-defenses

I'm making a fictional planet with a realistic ecosystem and I'm making a herbivore that is a shelled herd animal and is a main prey target for a carnivore which uses a barbed tail as a weapon. Its shell should also help significantly with protecting from radiation coming from a large blue giant which its planet orbits.

This should also blend with the idea of the planet's special orbit. It orbits around a blue giant and red dwarf. The orbital range of the planet for the blue giant is close enough to the red dwarf that it can pull it away from the blue giant for a small period of time before the plant orbits to a point where the blue giant's pull is strong enough to take it back. The planet doesn't get too close to the red dwarf so life is pretty, if not even more livable next to the dwarf which doesn't emit enough radiation and heat to breach the atmosphere in dangerous levels. A picture of the predator's tail is provided below.

In summary, the shell should protect from heavy radiation and the kind of tail shown in the picture. What characteristics should the shell have to fit these requirements?

[image: This is what the tail looks like, ignore the black and white bits, I took the image directly from the creature image I drew and the black and white are fur and bone]

Comment: Hi! Can you explain how that is a picture of your predator's tail? I don't really see what your planetary configuration has to do with the predator; care to explain? And please [edit] the answers directly into your question :)

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear. I meant that the shell should also be able to protect from the solar radiation from the blue giant. I'll try to organize it into sections but i'm not an organized person, i'm sorry.

Comment: Yellow dwarf: "live long and prosper✌️" Blue giant: "Boom boom boom boom I wanna go boom boom"

Comment: I tried to edit your post to fix grammar, spelling, capitalization, etc., but I'm having trouble understanding what you're actually asking. Is the shell only on the tail? Does the red dwarf actually have anything to do with this? Are you simply asking if the structure of a shell can protect an animal against radiation? How much radiation? Is the biological description necessary? I.E., why doesn't, "the creature's shell protects it from radiation" not a sufficient answer? (This actually helps us to determine what your goals and our limitations are.)

Comment: Also, I know you mean well and are trying, but that image of a tail doesn't really help. It's a blue splotch on a green background. It might help if we could see the whole creature, but I wonder if even that's true. I doubt the shape of the tail matters to the question and if the shell is only on the tail, what's protecting the creature from the radiation?

Comment: I get the impression that (a) the herbivore has a shell, and (b) the predator has a tail with a spike on it, like a scorpion. Unfortunately, given the information, the best answer I could give is "hard." Can you tell me why a turtle shell isn't the answer you're looking for?

Comment: any shell without gaps will work. that leaves a lot of options.

Comment: Grammar tip: "it's" only has an apostrophe when you're conjugating "it is". For its possessive form it's just "its".

Answer (score 1):

To start off, the armor for the herbivores would need to be thick to be useful against radiation. This thickness would likely be enough on its own to dissuade any sort of direct attack with a sharp tail - anything with enough thickness to absorb significant radiation would be virtually impenetrable, unless you have a comically oversized buzzsaw handy.

By my own research, assuming a predator the size of an Ankylosaurus (with a correspondingly sized tail), a full-speed swing would produce the force required to send a pinky-finger sized cross-sectioned projectile through 10 inches of paper before stopping. Given the wider spread of force across the tail's length, along with the difficulty in getting the tail to penetrate deeper due to the increasing width of the 'blade' as you go up the tail, which would stop the tail's movement much more quickly, I doubt the tail could make it through maybe five inches of armor, being generous. This might be enough for younger individuals with lesser shells, but with larger individuals, the tail might would likely get stuck before doing significant damage. Even using it on younger individuals might result in the tail getting stuck, putting the predator at risk of starving, being predated on or being stampeded by other herbivores. In summary, the tail would NOT be a serious way of getting through the shell - It would just be too thick.
[image]
(Ankylosaurus for comparison. Given that its tail is a notable adaptation that it has obviously leaned into, and it is reasonably large, I think it makes a good analagous creature to your predator.)

However, the tail might still be a deadly weapon, if it is used correctly.  The predator could use its tail to great effect by slashing at legs, heads, tails or any other exposed appendages. The predator might also attempt to use its tail to topple the herbivores, allowing it to get at their stomachs, which would likely be easily penetrated. The interactions and dynamic between the predators and herbivores would be oriented around how the predator intentds to attack the herbivores' weak spots, and how the herbivores attempt to defend themselves from this, giving you room for creative freedom to make whatever you like.

Additionally, I would recommend that the shell regularly replace itself, as neutron capture could eventually irradiate a permanent shell, reducing effectiveness. To this end, I would recommend either β-chitin or chitosan, to build a series of layers which would add upon each other to produce a very thick shell with many thin, flexible layers. β-chitin is commonly found in the internal skeletons of squids, and has some level of water regain value (the amount of extra water which can be stored in a material per unit of weight of the material.) ([https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/chitin#:~:text=Commercially%2C%20crab%20and%20shrimp%20shells,chains%20in%20the%20crystalline%20phase.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/chitin#:%7E:text=Commercially%2C%20crab%20and%20shrimp%20shells,chains%20in%20the%20crystalline%20phase.))

Chitosan, by contrast, is a de-acetylated form of chitin, and is only present in a few animals, and I'm not sure of its exact mechanical properties (besides that it can indeed be solidified into sheets), but it has a much higher moisture regain value, being able to retain an additional %12-20 of its weight in water (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0023643809002497). This would be very useful in protecting against radiation, as the water would give more absorption without needing to grow more shell.

So, either would work, and I imagine chitosan might be better, but β-chitin would be a safer bet, as it is conclusively known to be hard and is known to be produced by animals in the world. Chitosan, on the other hand, is not produced by any animals, although that may either be because no animal (yours notwithstanding) would get benefit from the unique properties of chitosan over the non-de-acetylated form, or it may be because the de-acetylation process is simply too complex for lifeforms to reasonably undergo. Whatever the case, I doubt anyone would take issue with you over it.

The shell might be between 3 and 12 inches (7.5-30cm) thick - just ballparking based on what would be reasonable in the circumstances.

If you choose chitosan, you would likely be using HMWC, or high molecular weight chitosan, as it is antibacterial (reducing risk of rotting diseases under or within the shell), creates more hydrogen bonds than medium or low weight chitosan (meaning increased moisture regain value), and is not as soluble in water or solutions as other chitosans, nor is it as bioactive as the others, meaning it won't react itself into gloop and become useless. HMWC also has more thermostability than others.
(all this from https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4360/15/13/2867)

Hope that helps!